# Making nested API calls using RxJS based on a condition using iif operator resulting in Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I am trying to use a conditional rxjs operator. I am checking if the data is stored in the `local storage`, return that, if not, make 2 HTTP calls to get the required data and return it.

Here's my code:

```
// making nested API calls
    loggedInUserDetails$ = this._getPoid().pipe(
      concatMap((userData: any) => this._userData(userData)),
      map((userDetails: any) => userDetails.legalName.nameLastFirst),
      tap((user: string) => this._storage.saveUserInStorage(user)),
      catchError(() => of('some dummy name')),
   );

  storedUserData$ = of(this._storage.getUserFromStorage());

  loggedInUsername$ = of(this._storage.getUserFromStorage()).pipe(
    mergeMap((username: string) =>
      iif(
        () => Boolean(username),
        this.storedUserData$,
        this.loggedInUserDetails$,
      ),
    ),
    tap(console.log),
  ); 


 loggedInUsername$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

**The above code returns Maximum call stack size exceeded**

> Observable.js:54 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/OuterSubscriber.js.OuterSubscriber.notifyError
>   (OuterSubscriber.js:12)
>       at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:18)
>       at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:59)
>       at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error
>   (tap.js:61)
>       at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:59)
>       at

Comment: why you repeat  of(this._storage.getUserFromStorage())? i think the true condition of the iif goes to an infinite loop... but needs more details

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say `mergeMap` is the appropriate operator in this scenario. You aren't looking to merge the observables, but instead switch it to another. Try with `switchMap` operator.

```js
loggedInUsername$ = of(this._storage.getUserFromStorage()).pipe(
  switchMap((username: string) =>
    iif(
      () => Boolean(username),
      this.storedUserData$,
      this.loggedInUserDetails$,
    ),
  ),
  tap(console.log),
);
```